# Choosing a role provider - ASP.net membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm using 2 membership providers on my Umbraco CMS.  1 provider is used for CMS users and the other is to be used for site membership.

I have 2 role providers too - UmbracoRoleProvider & AspNetSqlRoleProvider.  How do I access each one in the code?  e.g. when a new user registers, I'd like to add a role for them as "member", but it defaults to the Umbraco role provider because that is the default.

I thought I'd be able to do something like this:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(EmailAddress.Text, "Member", "AspNetSqlRoleProvider");
```

Or something similar, but can't find any info on it.  Can it be done over a few lines of code, or is it more complex than that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using multiple role providers is not supported out of the box. You could use the [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) to implement your own role provider that checks both for valid roles and memberships, but I would try to find a way to use a single role provider instead.

Comment: Okay I'll look to do that.  Thanks